# Number followed by hyphen

Tags: r, regex

I have dataframe which contains strings. Refer the code below -

```
mydf = data.frame(x=c("ads 1-x as", "sda 1-xxaa sad", "sda a-x sad"))
```

I want the word that follows pattern : numeric followed by hyphen followed by a single letter, to be replaced with numeric only.

**Expected Output -**

```
"ads 1 as", "sda 1-xxaa sad", "sda a-x sad"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` (or if there are more number of instances, with `gsub`) to match one or more digits captured as a group (`\\d+` - note the word boundary (`\\b`) before that) followed by a hyphen (`-`) and a single letter (`[A-Za-z]`) (to avoid matching it with more letters - use the word boundary -`\\b`) and replace with the back reference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
gsub("\\b(\\d+)-[A-Za-z]\\b", "\\1", mydf$x)
#[1] "ads 1 as"       "sda 1-xxaa sad" "sda a-x sad"
```